# greater-than-or-equal-to value in search builder is not displaying

Tags: smartgroups, search-builder

When creating a smart group I am no longer able to select the greater-than-or-equal-to value in the operator field. I tested it several times and the only time I can choose the greater-than-or-equal-to value is when it is the first search in my search builder. In the image you can see that I can not choose the value I want to modify the date accordingly. I am using CiviCRM 5.3.1

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I was able to replicate this bug on Civi 5.3.1 but not on the latest version (5.6.1).  An upgrade should take care of this for you.